# Nativescript infinite translate animation

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Hello I am trying to implement a moving background image on a NativeScript view.

The layout looks like this

> login.xml

```
<Page loaded="loaded" android:actionBarHidden="true">
<GridLayout>
<Image src="~/img/haloose_bg.png" id="bg"/>

<StackLayout orientation="vertical" verticalAlignment="center" id="sl_login">
...
</StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
</Page>
```

I want the `Image` to move in random directions on the background

I have tried the following approaches :

**1)Set Interval Approach**

> utils.js

```
utils.animateBG = function(container,id,duration){
        var newx = newy = Math.random() + 1.2;
        container.getViewById(id).animate({
            translate : {x: newx - 10 , y : newy + 70 },
            duration : duration
        });
}
```

> login.js

```
exports.loaded = function(args){
page = args.object;
setInterval(utils.animateBG(page,"bg",3000),3000);
}
```

I would then clear the interval when user taps on a button or leaves the view. This approach makes the app crash after 4 seconds.

**2) While loop approach**

> login.js

```
while(!user.hasClickedSomething){
    utils.animateBG(page,"bg",3000);
}
```

This approach makes the app freeze on white screen.

**3)Recursive approach**

Here I edited the animate the method:

> utils.js

```
utils.animateBG = function(container,id,duration,continueAnimation){
    if(continueAnimation){
        var newx = newy = Math.random() + 1.2;
        container.getViewById(id).animate({
            scale : { x: newx, y: newy},
            translate : {x: newx - 10 , y : newy + 70 },
            duration : duration
        }).then(function(){
            utils.animateBG(container,id,duration,continueAnimation);
        });
    }
}
```

Then I called it and passed `user.continueAnimation` as condition that should stop the loop. `user` is an observable view model bound to the page which has a `continueAnimation` field set to `true` by default.

> login.js

```
exports.pageloaded = function(args){
page=args.object; 
page.bindingContext = user;
utils.animateBG(page,"bg",3000,user.continueAnimation); 
}
```

I then try to set `user.continueAnimation` to `false` when I click on other buttons, but somehow it always stays true inside the method. This results on the animation never stopping, and if I go to another view and get back, the app freezes or crashes.

Has anyone implemented what I'm trying to do? Is there a better way of doing it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your #3 is actually almost correct; here is the fixed code:

```
var continueAnimation = true;
utils.animateBG = function(container,id,duration){
    if(continueAnimation){
        var newx = newy = Math.random() + 1.2;
        container.getViewById(id).animate({
            scale : { x: newx, y: newy},
            translate : {x: newx - 10 , y : newy + 70 },
            duration : duration } );
        }).then(function(){
            utils.animateBG(container,id,duration);
        });
    }
};
```

The continueAnimation variable MUST be a reference to a variable outside of the function, otherwise it will never get set to false and will always be passing "true" into its recursive brothers.   Now I would actually probably change to the code to be:

```
var continueAnimation = true;
utils.animateBG = function(container,id,duration){
    if(continueAnimation){
        var newx = newy = Math.random() + 1.2;
        container.getViewById(id).animate({
            scale : { x: newx, y: newy},
            translate : {x: newx - 10 , y : newy + 70 },
            duration : duration } );
        }).then(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
               utils.animateBG(container,id,duration);
            },0);
        });
    }
};
```

So that it is no longer recursive (callstack wise), but will make sure you don't ever exceed the call stack (as JS does have a pretty large CallStack limit, but if the person leaves this running and walks away, using a setTimeout will eliminate exceeding the callstack.

Answer (score 2):

There is also another different approach for infinite animation - using CSS-animations.
For example:

in your page.css

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    25%  { transform: translate(200, 0); }
    50%  { transform: translate(200, 200); }
    75%  { transform: translate(0, 200); }
    100% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
}


.img-logo {
   animation-name: example;
   animation-duration: 2s;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

in your page.xml

```
<StackLayout>
    <Image src="res://logo" class="img-logo"/>
</StackLayout>
```

[CSS-animations in NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/animation-css.html)

Comment: This approach looks great! The code doesn't work though =( I'll go through the docs and see what needs to be fixed!

Comment: It worked for me - try installing the latest NativeScript 2.0.0

Comment: Now it did! Thank you